# How to mock org.apache.spark.streaming.State with scalamock lib?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, scalamock

I write a unit test for "update function" of Spark.streaming.mapWithState and I need Mock the "org.apache.spark.streaming.State" parameter, but it's a sealed class, compiler  complains about an exception: illegal inheritance from sealed class State. How should I test my function?

Answer (score 0):

A sealed trait can only be extended in the same source file as it's declared. So Scalamock has no chance of mocking this type.